# How extract code from web site (code that appears with F12) in python

Tags: python, web, python-requests, extract, screen-scraping

I need to extract exactly the html code of a website that is displayed with F12 on a program python. I tried with requests.get(url) and driver.page_source but I only get the script (devoid of the values I need).

Comment: Use [tag:selenium].

Comment: Can you use `wget`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the "actual contents of the webpage" because the JS code needs to run first and the generated content needs to be rendered on the DOM.

Consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python), the answers should be helpful.